# Datediff round returns zero

Tags: php

I'm trying to run a datediff. I essentially want to say the number of days between 1st November 2022 and 1st November 2022 is ONE day.

When I attempt this, `$number_of_days` returned is 0. Can someone explain why this is and how to resolve?

```
$end = "2022-11-01";
$start = "2022-11-01";

$datediff = ($end - $start) + 1; // tried to fix

echo $datediff;

echo '<hr>';

echo ($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

$number_of_days = round($datediff / (60 * 60 * 24));

echo '<hr>';

echo $number_of_days;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dates you shown in the code are strings, they are not numerically "minusable". You need to convert them into an int of time first like this:

```
$end = strtotime("2022-11-01");
$start = strtotime("2022-11-01");

$datediff = (($end - $start)/60/60/24) + 1;
```

**Why doesn't it work**: If you try to subtract strings like this, PHP will auto-convert the strings into the boolean value true and then convert them into the integer 1. You divided it by `(60 * 60 * 24)` which results in a very small number `1.1574074074074E-5` which then be rounded into 0.

Comment: Amazing.
I've just replace $datediff with $number_of_days to resolve it. Thank you so much.

Comment: note: if you use this method and division, and cross a daylight saving time change, then you'll end up with a fractional part, and possibly the wrong number of integer days, so bear that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Your subtraction is using string values, not date values, so actually ends up as being 2022 - 2022, which equals zero...
(newer versions of PHP will complain "Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered")

You could convert to instances of `DateTime`, and then determine the difference that way:

```
$end = "2022-11-01";
$start = "2022-11-01";

// convert to DateTime
$dtEnd = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $end);
$dtStart = DateTime::createFromFormat('!Y-m-d', $start);

// get the difference in days
$days = $dtEnd->diff($dtStart)->format('%a') + 1;
```